# Is there any difference between .NET and ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net

What is the difference between .NET and ASP.NET? How are they related?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ASP.Net is built on the .Net framework to provide additional functionality around web development.

You might go look at the [wikipedia article on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework).  In particular, pay attention to the .Net Framework stack under the Versions section.

Comment: you mean to say it's a technology which is based on .net framework.

Comment: @user498432: The word "technology" isn't specific enough as both are "technologies".  Rather, asp.net is an additional set of class libraries and that ships with the framework to provide further functionality.  This is the same as LINQ, WPF, WinForms, etc.  They are all extensions of the framework.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET is a web technology that uses .NET Framework (among others) as the means to do web development tasks.

Answer (score 0):

C# and C#.net are same as C#.
.Net is a Code of Library that .net languages can talk to
.Net languages use CIL (Common Intermediate Language) which means that all start talking with same language 
.Net languages come in different flavor i.e; VB.Net,C#.Net
Asp.Net is a .Net framework that use .Net Library for making Web Sites.
The Web Forms which is the oldest way of making web sites and MVC is a new day technology.
You can say C# Desktop applications like WPF is use .Net technology and MVC is use Asp.Net technology.